# How to create a volume in a ZFS dataset and attach to a LXD container?

Tags: ubuntu, zfs, lxd

I'd like to create a volume in a zfs dataset:

```
sudo zfs create mypool/maildir
sudo lxc storage volume create mypool/maldir custom1
```

and got

```
error: not found
```

my create is sure to be wrong, what I intended to do is:

1. create a zfs dataset
2. use the dataset as disk and mount to a container

so if I re-install the system, I can create a container and attach the same dataset to the new container,

is this possible? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Your post does not really show what your pool or datasets look like, but here's one way you can do it.

Generally, you want to:

1. create the ZFS pool using ZFS directly, as you (probably) did with the `zpool create ...` command;
2. create a dataset for LXD to use as its assigned pool, as you seem to be doing with `zfs create ...`, using the `lxd init` step to make this assignment;
3. use LXC to create *volumes* within the LXD pool;
4. use the `attach-profile` sub-command to assign volumes to container profiles

I don't have enough information to use your data as an example, so I'll show you how I did mine, using LXD/LXC 3.0:

**Create the ZFS Pool and Dataset**

```
$ sudo zpool create -m /mnt/tank tank raidz3 <vdev1> <vdev2> ...
$ sudo zfs create tank/lxd
$ sudo zfs list
NAME       USED  AVAIL  REFER  MOUNTPOINT
tank       954M  1.31T  41.7K  /mnt/tank
tank/lxd   953M  1.31T  41.7K  /mnt/tank/lxd
```

**Give LXD its Dataset as a Pool**

```
$ lxd init
...
Name of the new storage pool [default=default]: lxd-pool
Name of the storage backend to use (btrfs, dir, lvm, zfs) [default=zfs]:
Create a new ZFS pool? (yes/no) [default=yes]: no
Name of the existing ZFS pool or dataset: tank/lxd
...
```

**Use LXC to Create the Volumes**

The following command creates a new volume called `dev-volume` within the pool called `lxd-pool` that we assigned above, and sets a size of 512GB. (You may use whatever numbers you need in your case.)

```
$ lxc storage volume create lxd-pool dev-volume size=512GB
```

If you're getting an `error: not found` you'll need to make sure you're using the commands correctly, that the arguments are in the correct order so that you reference things that actually exist, and so on. Using `lxc help <subcommand>` is very helpful.

**Attach Volume to Container Profile**

You'll want to assign the volume to a profile that will be used by a container. To do this, simply rely on the following command:

```
$ lxc storage volume attach-profile lxd-pool dev-volume dev-profile tank /mnt/tank
```

The command above attaches the volume `dev-volume` within the `lxd-pool` to a profile called `dev-profile` as a device called `tank` that gets mounted at file system path `/mnt/tank` within the container.

I hope this helps.